# Autohotkey conditional event consume

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to build following gesture:
Click And Hold Right Mouse Button, Click Left mouse button => fire browser back key

```
RButton & LButton Up::
    Send {Browser_Back}
return

~RButton::return
```

The problem is I want to consume the last "right button up" when release the right button after this hotkey was pressed. Effectively I dont want to see the context menu poppong up.

Any Help?

Edit: It would be nice if we can preserve right drag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to block the right button menu at all times.

```
rbutton & lbutton::Send, {Browser_Back}

rbutton::click r
```

Otherwise exclude the second line.

Update: Since you have now specified that you use "right-drag"
here is another idea (note: I don't use right-drag so I can't confirm anything):

```
rbutton::
Keywait, rbutton, T0.5
If (ErrorLevel) {
    Click r d
    Keywait, rbutton
    Click r u
} Return

lbutton::
if GetKeyState("rbutton", "P")
    Send, {Browser_Back}
Else {
    Click d
    Keywait, lbutton
    Click u
} Return
```

You will have to hold rbutton and left click then release rbutton within  0.5seconds, or raise the time.
The basic version simply won't work as far as I know. This is because using `&` will make rbutton only fire upon release.

If this still doesn't work you could try something even more complicated: [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=50600#p50600)
Update: I just thought of another variation:

```
Lbutton::
if GetKeyState("rbutton", "P")
    Send, {Browser_Back}
Else {
    Click d
    Keywait, lbutton
    Click u
} Return

rbutton up::
If (a_priorhotkey != "Lbutton" or a_timeSincePriorHotkey > 500)
    Click r
Return
```

Comment: This disables the right mouse drag. I guess this is not too much of a problem. If I can find anything else I'll have to do with this :)

Comment: @mamnun Please update your question to specify that; otherwise, my update won't be in context.